# How to add to the end to each value of the array -de -en -es?

Tags: php, wordpress

I make a plugin for tag filtering
And I would like to know how to add to the end of each tag -de -en -es?
I have a multilingual site and write every time
red-de, red-en, red-es, uncomfortable.

```
add_filter('pre_get_posts','exc_post'); 
function exc_post($query) {
    if ($query->is_category || ($query->is_home || ($query->is_feed) || ($query->is_tag)))  
    {
$X0 = plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ );  
$X0x = file_get_contents( $X0 . 'Text.txt');   
$X1 = explode (",", $X0x);  



        $query->set('tax_query', array(  
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' =>  $X1,  
                'operator' => 'NOT IN'
            )
        ));
    }
    return $query;
}
```

Comment: Are you using a multilingual plugin on your site? (eg. Polylang, WPML, etc)

Comment: yes, i have Polylang

Comment: Alright, give my answer below a shot and if it works please consider [marking it as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). If you have any further questions, just ask away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [array_map()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to add the prefix to each tag, and [pll_current_language()](https://polylang.wordpress.com/documentation/documentation-for-developers/functions-reference/) to retrieve the current language slug:

```
add_filter('pre_get_posts','exc_post');
function exc_post($query) {
    if ($query->is_category || ($query->is_home || ($query->is_feed) || ($query->is_tag)))
    {
        $X0 = plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ );
        $X0x = file_get_contents( $X0 . 'Text.txt');
        $X1 = explode (",", $X0x);

        // Append lang code to every tag
        $X1 = array_map('add_lang_suffix', $X1);

        $query->set('tax_query', array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' =>  $X1,
                'operator' => 'NOT IN'
            )
        ));
    }
    return $query;
}

function add_lang_suffix($tag) {
    return $tag . '-' . pll_current_language();
}
```

This will automatically append `-de`, `-en`, `-es`, etc. to every tag.